# how to make dropdown menu links drop down vertically without changing order of the navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to include a dropdown for one tab in my navbar and I'm trying things out (I used the demo from w3schools) but in order to make the dropdown links appear vertically (when i hover over) I need to put `display: inline-block;`, but this makes it so that my multimedia tab goes to the end of the navbar, switching places with my about bar
so basically I want my links to look like this :

[image: vertical links]

and my navbar to look like this

[image: navbar].

However, if I want the dropdown links to look like what I want, this happens

[image: navbar bad]

also it works in the demo but when i add my own code to customize the navbar, the links end up looking like this :

[image: bad links]

I tried to make it with `flex-box (using flex-direction: column)` and everything but it didn't work and i have no idea what to do, do you guys have any other suggestions/if I'm doing anything wrong? i want the about page to be at the end

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a dropdown menu in your navbar, where the dropdown options appear vertically when you hover over the dropdown trigger?

Comment: yes that is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took your code and did a little tweaking:

```css
      /* Dropdown Button */
   .dropbtn {
     background-color: #04AA6D;
     color: white;
     padding: 16px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border: none;
   }
   
   /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
   .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   
   /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
   .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     min-width: 100px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     z-index: 1;
     margin: auto;
   }
   
   /* Links inside the dropdown */
   .dropdown-content a {
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
     min-width: 100px;
     margin: auto;
   }
   
   /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
   .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
   
   /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
   
   /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
   .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
   
   topnav {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #9e2118;
   }
   
   .topnav a {
     float: left;
    
     color: #black;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
   }
   
   .topnav a:hover {
     background-color: rgb(187, 98, 98);
     color: black;
   }
   
   .topnav a.active {
     background-color: rgb(107, 0, 0);
     color: white;
   }
   
   .topnav .icon {
     display: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class **dropdown-content** change the display property value to **flex** and add **flex-direction** property in the same class with a value of **column**

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

and it will look like this
[image]

**flex-direction** will only work if the display value is flex/inline-flex

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: green;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
  
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
  background: green;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Multimedia</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```